# Where did this figure showing shifts in support between 2016 and 2020 come from?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, statistics, reference-request, exit-polls

[This article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2020/10/09/why-trump-is-losing/)  has an image showing shifts in support between 2016 and 2020. Where does this figure come from? While it says Pew Research Center, I can't find this figure on their site.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that The Washington Post made that figure using data from the two Pew Research surveys they link to in the paragraph preceding the figure:

[An examination of the 2016 electorate, based on validated voters](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2018/08/09/an-examination-of-the-2016-electorate-based-on-validated-voters/) from August 9, 2018, and

[Amid Campaign Turmoil, Biden Holds Wide Leads on Coronavirus, Unifying the Country](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2020/10/09/amid-campaign-turmoil-biden-holds-wide-leads-on-coronavirus-unifying-the-country/) from October, 9th 2020.

My evidence for this is: 1) that the figure doesn't appear in either article and 2) the figure contains some non-precise matches between the 2016 and 2020 data, which are shown in italics

Comment: Media outlets do usually usually make their own graphics in their own style.